# C++ map destruction

Tags: c++, dictionary, destructor

I want to clear a map inside the destructor, but I do not know whether it is empty or not. Is it okay if I clear it as follows.

```
for(std::map<int, int *>::iterator it = m_map.begin(); it != m_map.end(); ++it)
{ 
   delete it->second;
}
m_map.clear();
```

or should I also put an if condition around the above operation like if(!m_map.empty()){} in order to check whether it is empty or not.

Comment: The loop is fine. Nothing will happen if the map is empty. Also, you don't need to call `m_map-clear();`.

Comment: Are you sure? I think delete only deletes the pointers and we need to clear the map itself as well.Ok I will also remove clear. I got it. Thanks.

Comment: I am sure. The map will get cleared when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @AvbAvb: The compiler will add a destructor for `m_map` to your destructor for the class, so it will be cleared by that.

Comment: Would it be okay to use a smart pointer for memory management? This would could ease more operations than destruction.

Comment: @JanHerrmann Using a smart pointer would probably make everything else (slightly) more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

If the map is empty, `m_map.begin()` will be the same as `m_map.end()`, so the loop won't do anything. `m_map.clear()` (or rather `~std::map` will happen, but that will do `clear()` or the equivalent) will happen automatically by the destructor the compiler supplies as part of your destructor, so not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The code is ok for an empty map. The m_map.begin() will equal to m_map.end(), so the for loop body will not excute if the map is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If it's empty then the for loop won't execute, so it won't make any difference.